# Mysql Php Always get same return

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that is for direct calling that checks to see if a key is in the blacklist database. However, no matter what I try, including mysql_num_rows, it always returns that the value does not exist (returns 'OK')...

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$pin = $_GET['keycode'];

$cn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'serials') or die($cn->connect_error);
$sql = "SELECT keycode FROM blacklist";
$rs = $cn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
if ($row[keycode] == $pin) {
    echo "BL";
    return;
}
}
echo "OK";
$cn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: There's no need to loop all results in PHP, you can just use WHERE in SQL like: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blacklist WHERE keycode=$pin";

Comment: try it, where field=key

Comment: `mysql_*` won't work with `mysqli`. Did you use `mysql_num_rows` or the `mysqli` variation?

Comment: *"no matter what I try, including mysql_num_rows, it always returns that the value does not exist"* - that's because you can't mix different mysql apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this :

```
<?php  
  $cn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'serials');

  $pin =  $_GET['keycode'];

  $sql = $cn->prepare("SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE keycode = ?;");

  $sql->bind_param('s', $pin);// set $pin to type string and bind it to the query

  $sql->execute();// execute query

  $result = $sql->get_result();// get the result

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
     echo "Keycode Blacklisted";// inform that keycode found in blacklist
  }

  $cn->close(); 
?>
```

The problem with your code is :

1. You have not added single quotes to your `$row[keycode]` so change it to `$row['keycode']`
2. Your query was not selecting all columns but still you were treating the result as if it had several rows when you were using `$row['acolumn']`. Plus you were not using your `$pin` to check for equality first. By using `SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE keycode = ?;` you will check for equality without needing the `if` condition. So that's the explanation for my code change.

Comment: @downvoter - care to explain why?

Comment: I didn't vote but answers should have an explanation.

Comment: I didn't downvote and the answer looks correct'ish.  However, I would never upvote because the value should be passed in as a parameter, not by munging the string.

Comment: Answer looks correct, Who gives the minus?

Comment: @chris85 - Check the explanation, should be easy to understand now.

Comment: It is better. I'd parameterize, and remove the `while`, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php.

Comment: This has a whacking great SQL injection in the code, and readers should not use it! I acknowledge the effort and it is kind of you to help, but I think downvoting is appropriate. I will gladly reverse my DV if you can make it safe.

Comment: Also, you're `return`ing without closing in the case of a blacklist match.

Comment: @halfer - prevented SQL injection, check the new answer

Comment: @chris85 - removed the while loop - check it now

Comment: @GordonLinoff - made it parameterised.

Comment: Parameterizing removes the need for `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Looks good now.

Comment: Great, thanks for the positive response.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I learned quite a bit, espicially that you cant do a * with mysqli.